# Multiple reply URLS

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, wif

Background

I have a Single STS server to manage my authentication but I have several websites all of these use the same source files, and web config file.

[image]

Each website uses the variation in the URL (PDMNA, CPDEU, FIND) to establish what database it needs to connect to. So it is essential that the reply URL is correct.

This is where the issue starts, I can handle the AudienceUrls as shown below but the realm and reply I can only have one. Which means I always get sent back to PDMNA regardless of the original URL.

[image]

So the questions are as follows.

1. Can I have multiple realm and reply URLS?
2. Can I have a separate web.config file for each URL but maintain the single set of webfiles?
3. Is there another options?

Answer (score 1):

An application normally has a single realm;
you can dynamically change the reply adders by subscribing to the appropriate [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.redirectingtoidentityprovider.aspx) of the subobjects of the static [FederatedAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.web.federatedauthentication.aspx) class.
Finally, you can use web config transforms to specify a configuration per deployed application instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try the following "you can dynamically change the reply adders by subscribing to the appropriate event" and see how it goes. I will let you know.